# How to write polynomial expression as commutator form?

Tags: symbolic, packages, algebraic-manipulation

I want to write some polynomial expressions as commutator form. For example : 
$$
\frac{\text{BA}}{2}-\frac{\text{AB}}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}[A,B]
$$
or 
$$
\frac{\text{AAB}}{6}-\frac{\text{ABA}}{3}-\frac{\text{ABB}}{3}+\frac{\text{BAA}}{6}+\frac{2 \text{BAB}}{3}-\frac{\text{BBA}}{3} = \frac{1}{6}[A,[A,B]] - \frac{1}{3}[B,[B,A]].
$$
Here, $A$ and $B$ 's are the constant matrices. $AB$ is the product of $A$ and $B$. Also $[A,B]$ is Lie bracket of $A$ and $B$. So, how can I write the following expression as Nested Commutators with the help of Mathematica? Is there any generalized mathematica package or code?

$$
-\frac{\text{AAAB}}{24}+\frac{\text{AABA}}{8}+\frac{\text{AABB}}{8}-\frac{\text{ABAA}}{8}-\frac{\text{ABAB}}{4}-\frac{\text{ABBB}}{8}+\frac{\text{BAAA}}{24}+\frac{\text{BABA}}{4}+\frac{3 \text{BABB}}{8}-\frac{\text{BBAA}}{8}-\frac{3 \text{BBAB}}{8}+\frac{\text{BBBA}}{8}
$$
or
$$
\frac{\text{AAAAB}}{120}-\frac{\text{AAABA}}{30}-\frac{\text{AAABB}}{30}+\frac{\text{AABAA}}{20}+\frac{\text{AABAB}}{20}+\frac{\text{AABBA}}{20}+\frac{\text{AABBB}}{20}-\frac{\text{ABAAA}}{30}+\frac{\text{ABAAB}}{20}-\frac{\text{ABABA}}{5}-\frac{\text{ABABB}}{5}+\frac{\text{ABBAA}}{20}+\frac{3 \text{ABBAB}}{10}-\frac{\text{ABBBA}}{5}-\frac{\text{ABBBB}}{30}+\frac{\text{BAAAA}}{120}-\frac{\text{BAAAB}}{30}+\frac{\text{BAABA}}{20}+\frac{\text{BAABB}}{20}+\frac{\text{BABAA}}{20}-\frac{\text{BABAB}}{5}+\frac{3 \text{BABBA}}{10}+\frac{2 \text{BABBB}}{15}-\frac{\text{BBAAA}}{30}+\frac{\text{BBAAB}}{20}-\frac{\text{BBABA}}{5}-\frac{\text{BBABB}}{5}+\frac{\text{BBBAA}}{20}+\frac{2 \text{BBBAB}}{15}-\frac{\text{BBBBA}}{30}.
$$

With my best regards.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what "commutator form" means? Are the A's and B's separate variables, or are ABAA, AAAB, etc variables names in themselves?

Comment: Please post copy-and-pastable, properly formatted (click the question mark on the right-side of the editing toolbar for help) *Mathematica* code instead of screen-shots. People like to be able to copy and paste into their own copies of *Mathematica* for fast answering.

Comment: I have corrected the mistakes in the topic. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Note that *Mathematica* reorders `B*A` to `A*B` freely, so how do plan to input such polynomials?

Comment: You can produce the polynomials using this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0603016v1.pdf. There is a mathematica procedure in page 5. You can use $n=4$ or higher.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I wasn't clear about what I meant by "copy-and-pastable, properly formatted *Mathematica* code. What you've written is not easily copied and pasted directly into *Mathematica*. What we like is what you would type into *Mathematica* typed verbatim into code blocks in the post. Use either back-ticks or four spaces at the beginning of the line; see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update, December 22**

I've developed a version that is more robust. I *believe* it should work in general, but I'm sure there are some corner cases that won't work (and probably some-not-so-corner cases too).

As before we add rules to the almost-no-built-in-meaning `NonCommutativeMultiply` (`**`):

```
Clear[ncm]
ncm[a__] := NonCommutativeMultiply[a]
Unprotect@NonCommutativeMultiply;
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_ + c_, d___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b, d] + NonCommutativeMultiply[a, c, d]
a_?NumericQ ** b_ := a b
a_ ** b_?NumericQ := a b
(-a_) ** b_ := -(a ** b)
a_ ** (-b_) := -(a ** b)
Protect@NonCommutativeMultiply
```

For convenience, we define a format for the commutator:

```
Format[comm[a_, b_]] := DisplayForm@RowBox[{"[", ToString@a, ",", ToString@b, "]"}]
```

Then, in order to generate expressions *from* commutator forms, we define:

```
Clear[expandCommutator]
expandCommutator[expr_] := expr //. comm[a_, b_] :> a ** b - b ** a // Expand
```

We also define the function that converts OP's form into `NonCommutativeMultiply` form:

```
convertToNCMForm[expr_] := expr /. Thread[
   Variables[expr] -> ncm @@@ (ToExpression /@ # &@*Characters@*ToString) /@ Variables[expr]]
```

Finally, we define the function that puts expressions in commutator form as

```
generateCommutatorForm[expr_, vars_List] := Module[{
   rules = Join[
     ncm[#2, #1] :> ncm[#1, #2] - comm[#1, #2] & @@@ Subsets[vars, {2}]
     , {
      comm[a : _comm, b : Except[_comm]] :> -comm[b, a]
      , comm[a : _comm, b : _comm] /; Depth[a] > Depth[b] :> -comm[b, a]
      , ncm[a : _comm, b : Except[_comm]] :> ncm[b, a] - comm[b, a]
      , comm[ncm[a__, b_], c_] :> ncm[a, comm[b, c]] + ncm[comm[a, c], b]
      , ncm[a : _comm, b : _comm] /; Signature[{a, b}] == -1 :> ncm[b, a] - comm[b, a]
      , comm[x : comm[a_, b_], c : _comm] /; Depth[x] <= Depth[c] :> comm[a, comm[b, c]] + comm[b, comm[c, a]]
      }
     ]
   }, FixedPoint[Expand[# /. rules] &, expr]]
```

Examples:

- A simple one:

  ```
  expr = -1/2 comm[a, b]
  expr2 = expr // expandCommutator
  generateCommutatorForm[expr2, {a, b}]
  ```

[image]

- A more complicated one, from the post:

  ```
  expr = 1/6 comm[a, comm[a, b]] - 1/3 comm[b, comm[b, a]]
  expr2 = expr // expandCommutator
  generateCommutatorForm[expr2, {a, b}]
  ```

[image]

- A more-than-two-operator example:

  ```
  expr = 1/2 comm[a, comm[b, c]] - 1/3 comm[b, comm[c, a]]
  expr2 = expr // expandCommutator
  expr3 = generateCommutatorForm[expr2, {a, b, c}]
  expr2 === expandCommutator[expr3]
  ```

[image]

- A four-variable, three-times nested one (this does illustrate a limitation in that I don't simplify the resulting expression if there is a simpler expression in terms of commutators; clearly, the representation in commutators is not unique):

  ```
  expr = (1/2) comm[a, comm[b, comm[c, d]]]
  expr2 = expr // expandCommutator
  expr3 = generateCommutatorForm[expr2, {a, b, c, d}]
  expr2 === expandCommutator[expr3]
  ```

[image]

- The most complicated one from the post:

  ```
  expr2 = AAAAB/120 - AAABA/30 - AAABB/30 + AABAA/20 + AABAB/20 +
     AABBA/20 + AABBB/20 - ABAAA/30 + ABAAB/20 - ABABA/5 - ABABB/5 + 
     ABBAA/20 + 3 ABBAB/10 - ABBBA/5 - ABBBB/30 + BAAAA/120 -
     BAAAB/30 + BAABA/20 + BAABB/20 + BABAA/20 - BABAB/5 +
     3 BABBA/10 + 2 BABBB/15 - BBAAA/30 + BBAAB/20 - BBABA/5 - 
     BBABB/5 + BBBAA/20 + 2 BBBAB/15 - BBBBA/30 // convertToNCMForm;
  ```

[image]

```
    generateCommutatorForm[expr2, {A, B}]
```

[image]

**Original Post**

For this problem, we choose a normal-order: let's move all `A`'s to the left of all commutators, which are all moved to the left of all `B`'s. We will use `NonCommutativeMultiply` in order to be able to use symbols that don't commute.

First of all, if your expressions are in the form of

```
expr = BA/2 - AB/2;
```

then we can use the following converter to get into a form that uses `NonCommutativeMultiply`:

```
convertToNCMForm[expr_] := expr /. Thread[
   Variables[expr] -> ncm @@@ (ToExpression /@ # &@*Characters@*ToString) /@ Variables[expr]]
```

(This is sort of silly, since it should be put in this form to begin with, but since the OP has it in that form, we convert it first.) So, for instance,

```
convertToNCMForm[expr]
(* -(A ** B/2) + B ** A/2 *)
```

We need some rules for `NonCommutativeMultiply` that allow expressions to be automatically simplified. (For instance, we want the operation to distribute over addition.) Here's a set of rules that work:

```
ncm[a__] := NonCommutativeMultiply[a]
Unprotect@NonCommutativeMultiply;
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_ + c_, d___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b, d] + NonCommutativeMultiply[a, c, d]
a_?NumericQ ** b_ := a b
a_ ** b_?NumericQ := a b
(-a_) ** b_ := -(a ** b)
a_ ** (-b_) := -(a ** b)
Protect@NonCommutativeMultiply
```

Finally, we choose a nice format for the commutator:

```
Format[comm[a_, b_]] := DisplayForm@RowBox[{"[", ToString@a, ",", ToString@b, "]"}]
```

or

```
Format[comm[a_, b_]] := "[" <> ToString@a <> "," <> ToString@b <> "]"
```

Then,

```
comm[A, B]
(* [A, B] *)
```

---

Now, here's the meat of the problem. We use replacement `Rule`s to move symbols past other symbols, introducing commutators along the way in the form of `comm`. We put these rules in a function as follows:

```
Clear@generateCommutatorForm
generateCommutatorForm[expr_, {A_, B_}] :=
  Expand@expr //. {ncm[B, A] :> ncm[A, B] - comm[A, B], 
            ncm[B, comm[a__]] :> ncm[comm[a], B] - comm[comm[a], B], 
            ncm[comm[a__], A] :> ncm[A, comm[a]] - comm[A, comm[a]]
           } // Expand
```

Now!

```
expr = expr = BA/2 - AB/2;
expr2 = convertToNCMForm[expr]
(* -(A ** B/2) + B ** A/2 *)
```

and

```
generateCommutatorForm[expr2, {A, B}]
(* -(1/2) [A,B] *)
```

For a more complicated expression,

```
expr = AAB/6 - ABA/3 - ABB/3 + BAA/6 + (2 BAB)/3 - BBA/3;
expr2 = convertToNCMForm[expr]
(* A ** A ** B/6 - A ** B ** A/3 - A ** B ** B/3 + B ** A ** A/6 + (2 B ** A ** B)/3 - B ** B ** A/3 *)
```

and

```
generateCommutatorForm[expr2, {A, B}]
(* [A, [A, B]]/6 - [[A, B], B]/3 *)
```

Finally,

```
expr = -(AAAB/24) + AABA/8 + AABB/8 - ABAA/8 - ABAB/4 - ABBB/8 + BAAA/24 + BABA/4 + 3/8 BABB - BBAA/8 - 3/8 BBAB + BBBA/8;
expr2 = generateCommutatorForm[convertToNCMForm[expr], {A, B}]
```

[image]

If you want it in the form where the nested commutators are always in the second slot, apply the following function to the final expression:

```
toCanonicalForm[expr_] := 
  expr //. {comm[comm[x__], y__] :> -comm[y, comm[x]], 
            comm[-a_, b_] :> -comm[a, b],
            comm[a_, -b_] :> -comm[a, b]
           } // Expand
```

Then,

```
toCanonicalForm[expr2]
```

[image]

Comment: You are of course great. Thank you for help.

Comment: @drxy. Thanks for the accept! But note that this method is not very robust. For instance, it won't work for your last example. I may be able to work on this again some time in the future, but maybe I've given you enough to go on, and you can go the rest of the way to making this robust.

Comment: I'll try to make robust code for the calculation. If I have any problem, I will write here. Again and again thanks.

Comment: @drxy. New version! It's much better now. I took advantage of some of the commutator identities and figured out how to deal with some of the "stopping expressions", things like when there were commutators of commutators with a product of operators and when there were commutators multiplied together.

Comment: Oh my god! You are of course awesome.